# How to add value into collection

Tags: java

I have a Hashtable like this:

```
Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();
 ht.put("A", "one");
 ht.put("B", "two");
```

Then I called its `values()` methods to get its values and stored in the
 Collection object like this:

```
Collection<String> col = ht.values();
```

Now this collection object has these values:

```
 one, two.
```

Then I called `col.add(" three");` This time I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
```

I checked the API:

```
If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false)
```

The value which I added("three") to collection is unique,not duplicate.But I can do other operations like `remove()` and `clear()` operations on it.

Not able to call `add()`.Why it is not allowing to add?

Answer (score 7):

The collection returned by values() method in Hashtable does not support adding new elements.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#values%28%29):

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this Hashtable.
>   The Collection is backed by the Hashtable, so changes to the Hashtable
>   are reflected in the Collection, and vice-versa. The Collection
>   supports element removal (which removes the corresponding entry from
>   the Hashtable), **but not element addition**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer, Hashtable requires key-value pairs. You are only adding value and not key, hence it throws an exception.